# Parsing of language fragments

Tags: xtext

For better Unit testing of my language, I want to test every rule separately.

However, the `ParseHelper`can only parse input that fully corresponds to the defined grammar.

Consider a language like HTML. I want to test parsing paragraphs without having to nest them in html->head->body etc.

I think ANTLR offers similar possibilities.

Is this achievable in Xtext too?

Answer (score 1):

Github issue https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues/16 addresses this feature. I guess the next release will do what you need.